# Функция group_concat не работает sql

Tags: sql, vertica

Есть таблица в которой 2 колонки:

```
id категорий | атрибуты 
154673          67
454367          12
665544          45
639495          12
...
```

Есть дерево категорий, к каждой категории привязан атрибут. Нужно из таблицы сгруппировать те категории из первой колонки, у которых одинаковый набор атрибутов из второй колонки.

Пробовала такой запрос.

```
SELECT id категорий, group_concat(аттрибуты)AS all_attributes
FROM таблицы
GROUP BY категории;
```

В вертике ошибка: Function group_concat(int) does not exist, or permission is denied for group_concat(int)

Что можно сделать?

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: group_concat() - нестандартная функция, которая может быть не реализована в диалекте. Ищите замены. В Vertica это, вероятно, будет LISTAGG().

Comment: listagg валится по лимиту символов, получаются склеенные строчки больше 1000 символов

Comment: Может, уже пора бы и справку почитать, а? там параметр есть, max_length прозываемый - Вы уж не поленитесь почитать, зачем его придумали..